# loop through joined tables in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

For some time I have struggled with what I think should be a simple display of a joined result.  My code is as follows.

```
<h1>start test</h1>
<?php
    ee()->db->from('store_orders as so');
    ee()->db->join('store_order_items as si', 'so.id = si.order_id', 'inner');
    $query = ee()->db->get();

    echo '<h1>This is a list of all the channel titles999</h1>';
?>
<ul>
    <?php 
//      print_r($query->result());
        foreach($query->result() as $row)
            {
               echo '<li>' . $row->id . ' - ' .  $row->order_id . ' - ' . date('m/d/Y:G:i:s', strtotime($row->order_date)) . '</li>';
            }
    ?>
</ul>
```

In the foreach loop I want to display the results of the join to make sure that the order id is equal across the 2 tables.....it is not.

I've tried inner, outer, left and right on the join, each giving different results but never what I think should be the correct result...both fields should be the same.

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

BTY, I model my query in MS Access to get my basic syntax.

Thanks

Anthony Jaxon, Los Angeles, CA USA

Comment: Can you show us your tables structure, what you get and what's your expected result ?

Comment: look at this link

http://www.bnibooks.com/anthony_group/citest2

I expect the first 2 columns to have the same value....they dont.

Comment: I understand, but without your db structure we can't try to reproduce the issue. Also, what's ee() ?

Comment: ![Store_orders](http://sandbox.bnibooks.com/fileinfo1.jpg)

Comment: ![Store_order_items](http://sandbox.bnibooks.com/fileinfo2.jpg)

Comment: Both fields are int(10) unsigned.  The join does not throw up any errors but I was expecting the code in the foreach loop 
to show the same value for id and order_id

Comment: At the start of this project I was using the statement "$EE =& get_instance();" to create the codeigniter object.  Later  I discovered that the object was available in expressionengine as ee()-> without having to create an instance.

Comment: <code>
<h1>start test</h1>
<?php
 ee()->db->select('so.id, si.order_id, so.order_date');
 ee()->db->join('store_order_items si', 'so.id = si.order_id');
 $query = ee()->db->get('store_orders so');

 echo '<h1>This is a list of all the channel titles555</h1>';
 ee()->db->last_query() 
?>
<ul>
 <?php 
  print_r($query->result());
//  foreach($query->result() as $row)
//   {
//      echo '<li>' . $row->id . ' - ' .  $row->order_id . ' - ' . date('m/d/Y:G:i:s', strtotime($row->order_date)) . '</li>';
//   }
 ?>
</ul>

</code>

Comment: <blink>
      You would hate this if it weren't
      wrapped in a code block.
    </blink>

Comment: `this is a test`  
the above is an inline code block

Answer (score 0):

Because you do a `SELECT *` and both table have a field called "id", MySQL doesn't know which one you want.

You need to set an aliase to your fields

```
ee()->db->select('so.id, si.order_id, so.order_date');
ee()->db->join('store_order_items si', 'so.id = si.order_id');
$query = ee()->db->get('store_orders so');
```

Comment: On a side note, i don't know how Expression Engine works but, if it is pure CI you should separate your data access and your output and use the MVC approach.

Comment: Do I use the alias within the foreach look and if so, what is the syntax?

Comment: Nop, you just need to change the db query like I did in the answer.

Comment: I'm getting a message that the alias "so" in the "$query = ee()->db->get('store_orders as so');"  is not unique.  I will try an alternate alias and get back to you....thanks.

Comment: I made a mistake, there are no "as" on table alias. See my edit. Also, if you still get the error, can you tell me what ee()->db->last_query() gives you ?

Comment: <ul>
<?php  
 ee()->db->select('so.id, si.order_id, so.order_date');  
 ee()->db->join('store_order_items si', 'so.id = si.order_id');  
 $query = ee()->db->get('store_orders so');  

 echo '<h1>This is a list of all the channel titles555</h1>';  
 ee()->db->last_query()   
?>  
<ul>  
 <?php 
  print_r($query->result());
//  foreach($query->result() as $row)
//   {
//      echo '<li>' . $row->id . ' - ' .  $row->order_id . ' - ' . date('m/d/Y:G:i:s', strtotime($row->order_date)) . '</li>';
//   }
 ?>
</ul>

Comment: @Anthony You need to echo last_query() to see the query CodeIgniter has built. Sorry if it wasn't clear. FWIW, I just tried my solution with a fresh CI install and it worked correctly.

Comment: Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'exp_so.id' in 'on clause'

SELECT `so`.`id`, `si`.`order_id`, `so`.`order_date` FROM (`exp_store_orders` so) JOIN `exp_store_order_items` si ON `exp_so`.`id` = `si`.`order_id`

Filename: libraries/Functions.php(689) : eval()'d code

Line Number: 5

Comment: What is that library Functions.php ? When do you call it ? Obviously the alisas used after the ON clause is wrong.